# Python in django Template

Tags: python, django

How to integrate python code in django html template 
{{ python code }}  <% python code  %> {% python code %} 
are not working in html page

Comment: Put simply, you don't. You either use the template syntax or use views as they are supposed to be used. the templates aren't supposed to be a place for logic

Comment: The real problem is, I see many people who start development before reading the docs. You can not use a tool if you do not know how to use it! [Django Template Tags and Filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/), but read the tutorials first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentionned, you cannot (at least not out of the box and not without huge pain) directly embed Python code in an Django template, and as far as I'm concerned that's a GoodThing(tm) - the "server page" model (PHP, ASP1 etc) has long proven to be a failure wrt/ maintainability.

Now for the good news : Django's template system is extensible so you can provide your own [custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/), which is also a way to "embed" Python code in your template.

Answer (score 1):

Python is not PHP. You can't do that, at least with Django's default templating engine. Moreover, you don't need to do that, as this is done on purpose. Having a big logic in templates results in unmanagable and ugly code. Python code doesn't belong to templates. What belongs to templates is some data that you can pass to templates from Django views. Templates, however, include many features that you can use to build the UI. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) is a documentation that covers it.

Answer (score 0):

That is the way Django is designed. You cannot ask for the feature it does not have. If you find that the template code is too hard for you, then switching to another [framework](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views) might help